# how to update a state in react with an array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Tags: reactjs

`const [BoardState, setBoardState] = useState([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);`

I have to manually assign all indexes  like `setBoardState([0,1,2,changed item,4,5,6,7,8])`

Is there any way that I could update only one item in state and the rest remains the same `setBoardState(BoardState[0] = changed item)` something like this

Answer (score 3):

Yep, but you need to make a copy of the array first, then work on it.

For example:

```js
const updateIndex = (index, newValue) => {
  const newValues = [...BoardState];
  newValues[index] = newValue;
  setBoardState(newValues);
}
```